# How do I upload an image file to server and database, along with the values of JavaScript variables?

Tags: javascript, html, sql, ruby, sinatra

I have an HTML `form` for uploading images and answering survey questions. I want to make it so that after I choose an image, the form contents change to become the first question, then after I answer that the contents become the second question, etc.

Right now, I have the answers saved in JavaScript variables, but I don't know how to send those variables, and the image, to the server-side database.

Here's my `layout.erb` file, which contains the `form`. The JavaScript in this snippet is just for previewing the uploaded image:

```
<form action="upload_image" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div class="form_item">
  <p class="question">
    <img id="upload_preview" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" />
    <input id="upload_image" type="file" name="my_photo" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PreviewImage() {
            var oFReader = new FileReader();
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("upload_image").files[0]);

            oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                document.getElementById("upload_preview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
                // document.getElementById("upload_image").disabled = true
            }; // DONE: function (oFREvent)
        }; // DONE: function PreviewImage()
    </script>
  </p>
  <p class="question">Enter name here<input type="text" name="text_name" /></p>
  <button type="button" id="next_question">Next</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Once I click the next button, the contents of `p.question` change to the second question, which has the choices 'A','B','C','D'. Each are in a `<p>` tag (e.g., `<p class="answer">a</p>`).

My server-side database has the columns `image_path`, `text_name`, and `second_question`. The second item, `text_name` is the text the user types into the `<input type="text" name="text_name" />`.

How to I make it so that the user can send to the database a row containing the  `image_path`, `text_name`, and `second_question` data?

Answer (score 0):

You usually have to pass the file data through another language that can write files to the server, such as PHP. There are a lot of premade libraries out there for this, no need to reinvent the wheel.

The most open and useful I found is [this demo and its source](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html).

Comment: This helps a little, though what I'm trying to find out is how to send the image, along with what the user clicks for `text_name` and `second_question`.

Comment: I guess I don't understand? That library **does** upload the actual image file to the server. You then use the address of where it was uploaded to load it to a page, or manipulate it in some other way. If you want to send other parameters at the same time as the image, you would probably need to modify the upload library slightly or find a way for it to trigger a callback function.